# How is the taper of a bolt correctly notated? (Imperial)

Tags: bolting

I have a blueprint which states the following about two bolts which are used:
[image]

Does that mean that the *radius* of the bolt decreases by 1/16" every foot, or the *diameter?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the diameter.

If you applied that to the radius, then the taper would not match the part it would be fitted to.